# Automatically sleep when all users (ssh or GUI) are logged out?

Tags: ssh, suspend, power-management, remote, gnome-power-manager

I've got an Ubuntu 19.04 desktop that I sometimes use as a physical workstation, and sometimes log into using ssh or NoMachine.

In order to save power, I'm wondering if there's a way to make the computer automatically log off whenever there are no users, physical or remote, logged in.

I've tried setting "Suspend after 1 hour" in the power settings, but this seems to log off even if there are ssh users logged in.

Is there a way to enable this behaviour in Ubuntu?